# How do extract a JSON content, containing ISO8385 fields that have been stringyfied into a Java class, with matching fields?

Tags: java, json

I extracted a JSON content, and converted it to a single String, how do I convert that String I extract, into a Java class with matching fields?

Comment: By using Jackson ObjectMapper maybe?

Comment: How is ISO8385 related to your question? And what is it? A typo? At least wikipedia does not know it.